# Pine-script strategy risk allow_entry_in function

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I am writing code in pine script and am quite new to pine script.
I am using pinescript v5. Following is the code

```
if high > high[1]
    strategy.risk.allow_entry_in(strategy.direction.long)
else if low < low[1]
    strategy.risk.allow_entry_in(strategy.direction.short)
```

Pine script gave me following error / warning.

```
line 103: Cannot use 'strategy.risk.allow_entry_in' in local scope.;
line 109: Cannot use 'strategy.risk.allow_entry_in' in local scope.;
line 113: Cannot use 'strategy.risk.allow_entry_in' in local scope.
```

Is there any other way out to disable the trend in specific direction. If it cannot be done then I think this function is quite useless.

Comment: The `strategy.risk.allow_entry_in` are called only once, on the start of script calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Delete IFs and try (not sure if it works):

```
high_condition = high > high[1]
low_condition = low < low[1]
strategy.risk.allow_entry_in(high_condition ? strategy.direction.long : low_condition ? strategy.direction.short : na)
```

Also, I'm not sure that "na" value is valid as `strategy.risk.allow_entry_in` parameter, and it is possible that both your conditions are true at the same time, so delete IFs and also try this:

```
high_condition = high > high[1]
low_condition = low < low[1] 
both_condition = high_condition and low_condition
strategy.risk.allow_entry_in(both_condition ? strategy.direction.all : high_condition ? strategy.direction.long : low_condition ? strategy.direction.short : na)
```